# Literal numbering in arabic environment

Tags: numbering, arabic, front-matter

I want to produce pages numbered in literal way in arabic book environment, in the Frontmatter of a document instead of roman numbering in the usual way.
The order of the arabic letters counter for the computers is not the numbers order but it's another one. Note that the number of arabic letters is 28.
I give the way of literal numbering in arabic for computers, and the values coresponding to each arabic letter. This correspondence is given in the following tabulars:

[image]

This means for example, that the number 23 is not  represented by the lettre number 23, which is the arabic letter ث , but of the "letters"  كج, because the computer reads this command as 23=20+3  and replaces the number 20 by its corresponding letter ك and the number 3 by its corresponding letter ج.

To obtain the good literal representation of the numbers, I increase the counter 'page' by 9 at every new page , until the page number 20; after increase this counter by 99 until we arrive to the page number 28,  the number of arabic letters.

I try to do this, using the following commands and packages...

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{everypage}

\AddEverypageHook{\ifthenelse{\value{page}<11}
                {}
                {
                \ifthenelse{\value{page}<101}
                {\addtocounter{page}{9}} 
                {
                \ifthenelse{\value{page}<999}
                {\addtocounter{page}{99}}
                {}
                }
                }
                }
```

This gives a good way for the first steps of my purpose...but I have several problems about this:

1. The first problem is that I use the package 'changepage' to check even/odd pages, to background the odd pages with an image. Now this manipulation transforms all the pages in even pages. How can I do for changing only the pagemark but not the pagenumber ?
2. We can use this method when the number of paqes is lesser than 28. What about for the number of pages greater than 28.. I want a counter which reinitializes to 1 for the letter 29 and adds the first letter before the counter..something like aa, ab, ac... ax, ay,az.
3. The command \thepage refers to the label of the page before adding 9 (or 99). How to refer good  for the command \thepage ?
4. What's the command that makes the command '\frontmatter'  adopt the roman numberimg for pages ? How can we make the default style be this style of numbering (call it \arabicliteral) for pages in the preamble of the book in arabic environment..? (I think about a possible macro to introduce it in arabic packages...)

**Update**

I give the tex file which produced the 3 tabulars attached here, for clearness and after demand. I think that the arabic font "Simplified font" is used here because I think that it's available in almost all systems. If not I'll search about a fonte like this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Simplified Arabic}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\LR{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&  2&  3   &4& 5&  6   &7  &8  &9\\
\hline
 ا  &ب& ج&  د   &ه& و&  ز   &ح& ط   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\vspace*{14pt}

\LR{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
10& 20& 30  &40&    50  &60 &70 &80 &90\\
\hline
    ي&  ك&  ل&  م   &ن  &س& ع   &ف  &ص  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{14pt}
}

\LR{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
100 &200&   300 &400&   500 &600&   700 &800&   900 &1000   \\
\hline
ق   &ر  &ش  &ت& ث   &خ  &ذ  &ض  &ظ  &   غ   
\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
 \end{document}
```

**Update 2** based on the solution given 
Here is the solution given by @HeikoOberdiek, completed with the arabic font.
This is the tex file

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Simplified Arabic}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}

    \usepackage{alphalph}

% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad_numerals
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@arabicliteral@symbol}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
  \or ا\or ب\or ج\or د\or ه\or و\or ز\or ح\or ط\or ي%
  \or ك\or ل\or م\or ن\or س\or ع\or ف\or ص\or ق\or ر%
  \or ش\or ت\or ث\or خ\or ذ\or ض\or ظ\or غ%
  \else
    \@ctrerr
  \fi
}
\newalphalph\@arabicliteral{\@arabicliteral@symbol}{28}
\newcommand*{\arabicliteral}[1]{\@arabicliteral{\value{#1}}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand*{\thetest}{\arabicliteral{test}}
\newcommand*{\printtest}{\thetest~(\the\value{test})}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{test}{1}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest, \dots,

\addtocounter{test}{22}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest, \dots,

\addtocounter{test}{24}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\stepcounter{test}\printtest,

\end{document}
```

It's compilation is given,  (one letter per line and read it in RighttoLeft mode, as arabic !)

[image]

Comment: to answer just (4): in the definition of `\frontmatter`, page numbering is set up to be `\pagenumbering{roman}`.  so for a book in arabic, that should be replaced by something more appropriate.  this definition is in `book.cls` and equivalent document classes, and should be amenable to modification using one of the "patch" techniques.

Comment: Thanks... This command would be replaced by \pagenumbering{literalarabic}, where 'literalarabic' will be the name of this kind of counting letters...

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna I don’t understand how the examples at the bottom at your question relate to the table you give at the top.  According to your table, 25 should be written as كه (not ظ), then 25 as كو, (not ظ) etc.  Are you sure Heiko’s code does what you want?

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer Yes The Heiko's code does exactly what I want. I think that you make some confusion between letters... The arabic letter number 25 is the letter ذ not the letter ظ... There's 28 letters in arabic alphabet not 26. You can see in my update (the list one letter per line) that there's the letter number 25 in the list and it's the good letter...ذ

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Yes, I got the single letters wrong, but whatever.  In any case the beginning of your question is irrelevant to what you actually want to do.  I think you should remove it.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer I don't understand what means "irrelevant" for you. The Heiko's code do what I want exactly. I want to obtain a counter which gives the abjad arabic letters in order, from 1 to 26... It's not explicit but it's the origin of the problems I've talked about

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna It’s not useful for answering your question, that’s what irrelevant means.  You don’t care about the numeric values of the letters, so you shouldn’t mention it.  Anyway, glad Heiko’s solution worked for you.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer I think that it was clear that my problem were in making the computer put the good order of the arabic letters... you can find it in some sntences like "To obtain the good literal representation of the numbers, I increase the counter 'page' by 9.." and others... Any way I accept your remark that it was not very explicit. Then Heiko has the merit of having guessed the origin of my problem.

Comment: Now I have answered my question and said to @HeikoOberdiek to give another answer with an arabic font, in a comment of it's answer.  So I would delete my updates when he will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue 2: Package `alphalph` provides formatting commands for counters, which uses a limited set of symbols. There are different methods for extending the allowed range of values. The default method is the method of the question and shown in the example below.

Issue 1: If the counter formatting command of the previous paragraph is used, then the counter values are still the normal values, increased by 1 for each `\stepcounter`. Therefore the odd and even detection should work as normal using the value of the counter (`\value{<counter>}`).

Issue 3: With the redefinition of `\thepage`, the arabic literal appearance is also used in references.

Issue 4: `\pagenumbering` automatically redefines `\thepage` with the specified counter formatting command and resets the page counter to 1.

Example which uses the symbols `A` to `Z`, `*`, `+` instead of the Arabic glyphs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alphalph}

% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad_numerals
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@arabicliteral@symbol}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
  \or A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J%
  \or K\or L\or M\or N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T%
  \or U\or V\or W\or X\or Y\or Z\or *\or +%
  \else
    \@ctrerr
  \fi
}
\newalphalph\@arabicliteral{\@arabicliteral@symbol}{28}
\newcommand*{\arabicliteral}[1]{\@arabicliteral{\value{#1}}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand*{\thetest}{\arabicliteral{test}}
\newcommand*{\printtest}{\thetest~(\the\value{test})}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{test}{1}\printtest,
\stepcounter{test}\printtest,
\stepcounter{test}\printtest, \dots,
\addtocounter{test}{22}\printtest,
\stepcounter{test}\printtest,
\stepcounter{test}\printtest,
\stepcounter{test}\printtest,
\stepcounter{test}\printtest,
\stepcounter{test}\printtest,
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Extended example

I assume, that the Arabic literal digits should not combine, if the numbers exceed 28. The following example achieves this by putting the digit into `\mbox`. Also the example shows, that page references work
as usual. And `\pagenumbering` enables the "Arabic literal" page numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Simplified Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{FreeSerif.otf}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{lmroman10-regular.otf}

\usepackage{alphalph}

% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad_numerals
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@arabicliteral@symbol}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    \ifcase#1%
    \or ا\or ب\or ج\or د\or ه\or و\or ز\or ح\or ط\or ي%
    \or ك\or ل\or م\or ن\or س\or ع\or ف\or ص\or ق\or ر%
    \or ش\or ت\or ث\or خ\or ذ\or ض\or ظ\or غ%
    \else
      \@ctrerr
    \fi
  }%
}
\newalphalph\@arabicliteral{\@arabicliteral@symbol}{28}
\newcommand*{\arabicliteral}[1]{\@arabicliteral{\value{#1}}}
\makeatother


\newcommand*{\test}{%
  \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
    This is page \the\value{page} or \foreignlanguage{arabic}{\thepage}.
  \end{otherlanguage}
  \label{page\the\value{page}}
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabicliteral}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
List of page references:
\end{otherlanguage}

\pageref{page1}, \pageref{page2}, \pageref{page3}, \dots,
\pageref{page25}, \pageref{page26}, \pageref{page27}, \pageref{page28},
\pageref{page29}, \pageref{page30}, \pageref{page31}, \dots,
\pageref{page56}, \pageref{page57}, \pageref{page58}, \pageref{page59}
\medskip

\test\test\test

\addtocounter{page}{21}% omitting some pages

\test\test\test\test\test\test\test

\addtocounter{page}{24}% omitting some pages

\test\test\test\test

\end{document}
```

As result, the list of page references is shown:

> [image: Result]

Comment: I think that you are in the good direction. would you see my update where you can find the tex file which produced the tabulars in my post. Note that the arabic font "Simplified font" is used here because I think that it's available in almost all systems. If not I'll search about a fonte like this.

Comment: Would you please give another solution, using the arabic font, which can be based on the second update of my post. This will be I think the definitive answer. Many thanks for this brilliant answer

Comment: I just saw your update. It's exactly my purpose. Thanks

Comment: I just saw that you are the author of this package. Congratulations for this very useful one. I think that I'll use it too for an arabic-english glossary or dictionnary. Thanks